# Servlet to access DAO and invoke a working method (java)

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist, dao

I am having trouble getting a servlet to work in my dynamic web project. I have a method in my StudentUtils class which works fine. It connects to my sql database and prints the contents to the console. See below.

```
public class StudentUtils {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

getAllStudents();

}   

public static void getAllStudents() throws Exception {

    try {

        Connection dbase = getConnection();
        String mysql = "select * from course";

        PreparedStatement output = dbase.prepareStatement(mysql);

        ResultSet rs = output.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) { 

            ArrayList <Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

            Student s = new Student(null, null, null);

            s.setStudentID(result.getString(1));
            s.setStudentName(result.getString(2));
            s.setStudentLevel(result.getString(3));

            list.add(s);

            System.out.println(s.toString());

            System.out.println("added"); } } 

    catch(Exception e) {

            System.out.println("could not add");
    }
```

This method when run prints each of the students to the console screen and the message `added`. However, I need to create a servlet which runs this method.

So far, in my servlet, I have created an instance of my dao (studentUtils) and an empty array list but then I am stuck with trying to populate the array list using the method in the dao. See below.

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    StudentUtils studetUtils = new StudentUtils();
    ArrayList <Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Any help in getting my servlet to populate this array list using my method in the dao would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't getAllStudents() return list?

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getAllStudents()` should probably return `List<Student>`. Also, note that in your current implementation the `List` is created inside the loop, re-creating it in each iteration, which is probably not the behaviour you want. You should create it outside the loop.

Apart from that, you should probably close your resources like `Connection` after using them.

Comment: Thanks. I have added List<Student> to my method and set the return. I have also moved the list to outside of the loop. What do I need to add to my servlet to iterate over this is/run the method?

Comment: @JavaNewbie: You can call `List <Student> list = StudentUtils.getAllStudents()`  in your servlet and then output something or (better) use a JSP as described in the duplicate question.

Comment: When I do that and run the servlet, I get the `System.out.println("could not add")` exception from the DAO (StudentUtils).

Comment: Then use `e.printStackTrace()` to find out what exception is thrown

Comment: I get a Null Pointer Exception at getAllStudents(). It also shows an empty arraylist as I have printed that to console too.

Comment: Should I be putting the 'List <Student> list = StudentUtils.getAllStudents()' in the doGet method? I have spent hours on this now and not got anywhere.